# How to deploy React laravel vite website on Hostinger?

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, vite

I've spent the whole last two days trying to deploy my Laravel React Vite website on Hostinger
I followed The instructions from Hostinger docs as below:
I uploaded my website.
created new .env and add my configs.
created a database.
added build folder from react vite after running "npm run build" to the public folder.
edit resource/view/welcome.blade.php with the build js and css src as below @vite(['public/build/assets/app.a0a7c860.js', 'public/build/assets/app.69041b03.css']).
I have already .htaccess file in public folder which is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

it still gives me 403 error Although it works correctly on localhost
I tried to add new .htaccess in the project directory
as below

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

now it gives me 500 server error
I am in doubt that hostinger couldn't recognize my project structure
How to solve that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution
after running "run build" and making my production version of React application
I attached welcome.blade.php (the main blade) to the production version by adding

```
@vite(['resources/js/app.jsx', 'resources/css/app.css'])
```

instead of

```
@vite(['public/build/assets/app.a0a7c860.js', 'public/build/assets/app.69041b03.css']).
```

although there is no js or css files in the resource directory but I think vite will automatically route to public build folder when it can't find any files in the target directory.